# Enabling one interface breaks connectivity on another

Tags: centos, ip, centos6, networking

I got a server with 2 NIC's.

One is the external interface, that has a public IP.

When only that interface is up, I can ping it fine from our internal network.

When I enable the second interface with the internal IP address on, I cannot ping the external IP anymore from the internal network. I can however ping it from a server on another internet connection.

I have been dealing with this for quite some time, and I really cant figure out why it won't work..

I have rebooted the server numerous times, without effect.

Interface configurations are as follows:

**ifcfg-eth0 (External)**

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:24:81:82:D2:26"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="d8c860fb-eab3-410c-a137-b100fa77ca51"
NETMASK="255.255.255.240"
IPADDR="7x.6x.1xx.1xx"
```

**ifcfg-eth2 (Internal)**

```
DEVICE="eth2"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:23:7D:9C:CA:A7"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="d544ec14-80fa-4765-bec4-e616b0b86bb8"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
IPADDR="192.168.11.15"
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=HOSTNAME
GATEWAY=7x.6x.1xx.1xx
```

**Routing table**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
7x.6x.1xx.1xx   *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
default         ip07x06x1xx1xx. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I am pinging from a computer in the 192.168.11.0 network. There is a hardware firewall between them, but the logs show nothing of interest.

They are connected to the same switch on the 192.168.11.0 network.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the IP of the machine you are pinging from and how they are connected. Do you have firewall enabled?

Comment: I have added the details to the question.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen WHAT TYPE OF HARDWARE FIREWALL?

Comment: @ewwhite Astaro ASG 220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And in general, modify your config to disable the NetworkManager control with: `NM_CONTROLLED="no"`. Also disable the NetworkManager service if it's running...

See if that helps first.

Outside of that, what is the source of your ping? 192.168.11.x?

Comment: Setting `NM_CONTROLLED="no"` didn't change anything - still doesn't work. The service networkmanager does not exist on my system. I have added some detail to the question about the source, but yes it is from the 192.168.11.0 network.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?